# Is ozone paramagnetic?

Tags: phase, magnetism, allotropes

[This answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/8839) shows why ozone should be diamagnetic. Still, [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozone) says it is weakly paramagnetic, having *positive* magnetic susceptibility $χ = \pu{+6.7E−6 cm^3 mol^-1}.$ There's a paper discussing it [[1](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF03172553)], saying it's only a value reported for liquid $\ce{O3},$ but it's paywalled. What is the reason for such discrepancy?

#### Reference

1. Anantakrishnan, S. V. The Structure of Ozone—An Interpretation of Its Magnetic Susceptibility. *Proc. Indian Acad. Sci. (Math. Sci.)* **1947**, 25 (6), 520. DOI: [10.1007/BF03172553](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF03172553).

Comment: The 1947 paper you cite concludes that "Calculation of magnetic susceptibility for the different valence bond
structures indicate that ozone should be diamagnetic, the susceptibility
being about -18 x 10^6 while reported experimental values show that it is
feebly paramagnetic in the liquid state, diamagnetic values being reported
for the gaseous state."

Comment: Basically when you think about such questions, you have to also think about the state of that compound/element and also the temperature. Ozone can be a gas, liquid, or a solid. This is how you can critically analyze the thoughts.

Comment: OP can read another open access article on ozone's magnetic behavior. It is dated but you can enjoy the original experiments. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1085222/

Comment: https://doi.org/10.1080/00268978300100581 might be of interest: "Ozone is a quite exceptional molecule in several respects; it is van Vleck paramagnetic, there is extreme antishielding of the nuclei and the dependence of both χ and σ on small changes of the geometry is fantastic."

Comment: It is also difficult to determine experimentally, since ozone is non-cooperative. See Derek Lowe on working with ozone and its derivatives. https://www.science.org/content/blog-post/things-i-won-t-work-peroxide-peroxides .

Comment: The [wikipedia article about ozone](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozone) says that it is diamagnetic, not paramagnetic, but I'm not sure if that's a recent edit or not.

Comment: @Bli231957 It's magnetic susceptibility confirms that it is a weekly paramagnetic substance.